# Cant scroll down on my webpage after adding banner images

Tags: javascript, html

I added a couple of banner images that change based on the nav button clicked but after I click the back button I cant scroll down on the webpage.

Here's the code

```
  <!-- Banner -->
<div class="slideshow-container">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="assests/banner.webp" alt="Image 1">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="assests/banner2.webp" alt="Image 2">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="assests/banner3.webp" alt="Image 3">
        </div>

        <!-- Navigation arrows -->
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    // Function to display the current slide
    function showSlide(n) {
        // Wrap around to the first slide if exceeding the number of slides
        slideIndex = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;

        // Hide all slides
        for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        // Display the current slide
        slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
    }

    // Function to navigate to the previous or next slide
    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlide(slideIndex + n);
    }

    // Display the first slide
    showSlide(slideIndex);
</script>
```

I want to be able to scroll down the webpage but instead it just keeps move the page up when I try to scroll down

Answer (score 0):

The codes you provided here is just fine and working perfectly. You can check it below. I added some space below the banner so that you can scroll.

I think the issue is in the remaining codes you have. If you can provide them then it is possible to test and find the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- Banner -->
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <!-- Slides -->
  <div class="mySlides">
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/400/400" alt="Image 1">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/400" alt="Image 2">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/g/400/400/paris" alt="Image 3">
  </div>

  <!-- Navigation arrows -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div style="height: 3000px; background: green; margin-top: 30px;"></div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

// Function to display the current slide
function showSlide(n) {
  // Wrap around to the first slide if exceeding the number of slides
  slideIndex = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;

  // Hide all slides
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Display the current slide
  slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
}

// Function to navigate to the previous or next slide
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlide(slideIndex + n);
}

// Display the first slide
showSlide(slideIndex);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```